# how to fix TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

> Error
>
> File "", line 22, in  sheet['D3'] = '= SUM(G3:AZ3)'
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

I tried several methods but none worked

my code

```
import openpyxl module
import openpyxl
sb="lists.xls"

wb = openpyxl.Workbook(sb)

sheet = wb.active

sheet['D3'] = '= SUM(G3:AZ3)'

wb.save(sb)
```

I expect the code to run without error.

Comment: `wb.active is None`. You need to figure out why that is the case.

Comment: If the error is in line 22 then you are not providing the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sheet` seems to be None. Are you looking to open a file and not write one? Perhaps this might help you:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

sb="lists.xls"

wb = load_workbook(sb)

sheet = wb.active

sheet['D3'] = '= SUM(G3:AZ3)'

wb.save(sb)
```

Also: Note that openpyxl does not support the .xls format. It will not be able to process your file unless you convert it to a format that openpyxl can support.

Answer (score -1):

TypeError is mostly because of mixing different types of data! For example, trying to do addition on integers with strings! According to code, the sheet may be a list and you are trying to add key and value to a dictionary! Try to check if you are accessing a dictionary rather than a list!

This might help you:

```
# Declare a dictionary
sheet = {}

# now you can add data to that dictionary
sheet['D3'] = '= SUM(G3:AZ3)'
```